# Difference in meaning between "Passe-moi le ballon" and "me passe le ballon"?

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, verbes-pronominaux

From my textbook : ***Passe-moi le ballon***

which means : ***pass me the ball***

and I was wondering if the meaning is different if we use the verb ***passer*** in a reflexive way :  *** me passe le ballon***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Passer* and *se passer* (reflexive) have different meanings.

Passe-moi le ballon is the imperative of the verb ***passer***.

*me passe le ballon* could be found in a sentence where *passer* is not in the imperative and has a subject, for example:

- *Mon ami me passe le ballon.*
  My friend passes me the ball

where *me* is the direct object pronoun for the first person singular. And the verb is not reflexive in that case.

---

***Se passer*** (reflexive) means "to happen" or "to take place".

- *Cette histoire se passe à Paris.*
  This story takes place in Paris.
- *Que se passe-t-il ?*
  What's happening?